# How can I get a list of keys from Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using C# and Json.NET. If I have a JObject, I want a list of the keys within the object, similar to how `object.Keys()` returns the keys within the object. This seems like it'd be obvious, but I'm having a rough time finding a way to do this.

**Edit:**
I'm traversing through the object, and I want to spit out all the keys in the object as I go through. I realize that this example will result in seeing the same key multiple times, and that's OK for my needs.

```
public void SomeMethod(JObject parent) {
    foreach (JObject child in parent.Children()) {
        if (child.HasValues) {
        //
        // Code to get the keys here
        //
        SomeMethod(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give a code example which you're using? Anyway try smth like this JArray sizes = (JArray)jObject["Keys"];

Comment: Unfortunately that was not successful. `object["Keys"]` returns the value of the key with the name "Keys"

Answer (score 161, accepted):

```
IList<string> keys = parent.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

Documentation: [**JObject.Properties**](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JObjectProperties.htm)

Comment: Has this been remove as of 5.0.8 version? Because I can't no longer get the Keys for a JObject.

Comment: @bigaj Nope, it has not...just tested this exact code on 5.0.8 and it appears to work fine for me

Comment: @Big AJ: did you import System.Linq? It's required to do the Select() query and won't be available without it.

Comment: throws: error CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.

Comment: Great use case for LINQ. The more I use LINQ the more I like it (when it's appropriate).

Answer (score 31):

From [Converting a JSON.NET JObject's Properties/Tokens into Dictionary Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161615/converting-a-json-net-jobjects-properties-tokens-into-dictionary-keys?rq=1)

You can simply convert the `JObject` into a Dictionary object and access the method `Keys()` from the Dictionary object.

Like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
//jsonString is your JSON-formatted string
JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
Dictionary<string, string> dictObj = jsonObj.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

You can now access those keys via the `dictObj.Keys()` method. You can see if a key exists by performing `dictObj.ContainsKey(keyName)` also.

Obviously, you can format the Dictionary however you want (could be `Dictionary<string, object>`, etc.).