# Problems with handling Dictionary in JObject (Newtonsoft.Json)

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this json object.

```
{  
   "Apparel":[  
      "Athlete",
      73
   ],
   "Freeze":[  
      "Coin",
      19,
      "Fur",
      37,
      "Grade",
      72
   ],
   "Lobster":[  
      "Node",
      18
   ]
}
```

I read it in a string and convert it to a JObject like this:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
JObject myobj = JObject.Parse(mystr);
```

How should I go about fetching all the keys {"Apparel", "Freeze", "Lobster"} ?

---

If I do something like this:

```cs
    List<JToken> mylist = myobj.ToList<JToken>();
    int l = mylist.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(mylist[i]);
    }
```

It prints:

```
    "Apparel": [
      "Athlete",
      73
    ]"Freeze": [
      "Coin",
      19,
      "Fur",
      37,
      "Grade",
      72
    ]
    "Lobster": [
      "Node",
      18
    ]
```

The values `{"Apparel", "Freeze", "Lobster"}` are not constant and could change. I know I can do some regex patches to get what I want from the string but I don't want to go down that road, unless it's a last resort. Please Help.

Comment: So you want only the `Keys` ?

Comment: Yes. Because I can get the values using the `Keys`. For example `Debug.WriteLine(myobj.SelectToken("Apparel"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jobject properties method,

```
IList<string> keys = parent.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

taken from here

[How can I get a list of keys from Json.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522358/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-keys-from-json-net)