# How to fetch keys from JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, api

JSON :

```
{"From":
{"CHF":{"Rate":0.91640105,"AsAtDate":"2016-04-19T00:00:00"},
"DKK":{"Rate":0.13437824,"AsAtDate":"2016-04-19T00:00:00"},
"EUR":{"Rate":1.0,"AsAtDate":"2016-04-19T00:00:00"},
"GBP":{"Rate":1.25985769,"AsAtDate":"2016-04-19T00:00:00"},
"PLN":{"Rate":0.23213581,"AsAtDate":"2016-04-19T00:00:00"},
"RON":{"Rate":0.22338218,"AsAtDate":"2016-04-19T00:00:00"},
"SEK":{"Rate":0.10868521,"AsAtDate":"2016-04-19T00:00:00"}},
"To":"EUR","RequestedDate":"2016-07-08T00:00:00"}
```

I want to fetch list of keys under from.
Eg. list should return keys all values like DKK, EUR,GBP .
C# code is required to deserialize JSON.

I am able to fetch values from JSON but not keys.

Comment: Please show your code which fetches the values so that one is able to see which library (if any) you are using and can provide an appropriate example in that way

Comment: JToken token = JObject.Parse(response.Content);   ActualCurrencies.Swiss_Franc = (string)token.SelectToken("From.CHF.AsAtDate1");

Comment: Need somthing to fetch in dictionary or string array list to fetch Keys values

Comment: Dupe to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522358/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-keys-from-json-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create classes to match your json Format, and then read the keys:

```
public class CurrecyConversion
{
    public Dictionary<string, CurrencyRate> From { set; get; }
    public string To { set; get; }
    public DateTime RequestedDate { set; get; }
}

public class CurrencyRate
{
    public decimal Rate { set; get; }
    public DateTime AsAtDate { set; get; }
}
```

You need to download this [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) (Right Click Project > Manager Nuget Packages)

**Usage:**

```
CurrecyConversion result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.
                                        DeserializeObject<CurrecyConversion>(jsonText);

List<string> keys = result.From.Keys.ToList();
foreach (var key in keys)
    Console.WriteLine(key);
```

Result:

```
CHF
DKK
EUR
GBP
PLN
RON
SEK
```

Comment: Im using IRestResponse in place of jsonText

Comment: @jayeshmhatre just get the josn string out of the response and proceed with the above logic.

Comment: @jayeshmhatre `string jsonText = response.Content;`

Comment: Error 15 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,CoreAnalytics.TestFramework.WebAPI.CurrencyRate>.KeyCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,CoreAnalytics.TestFramework.WebAPI.CurrencyRate>.KeyCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\mhatrejv\Desktop\CoreAnalytics.TestFramework sample project\CoreAnalytics.TestFramework\EMLAPIData.cs 370 50 CoreAnalytics.TestFramework.WebAPI

Comment: @jayeshmhatre add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file