# Get absolute path of JSON object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON object:

```
{
  ""settings"": {
    ""general"": {
      ""database"": { ""type"": ""PostgreSql"" }
    }
  }
}
```

The absolute path of my JSON object would look like this: `settings/general/database/type`

I tried to get all the keys with the first solution of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522358/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-keys-from-json-net):

```
IList<string> keys = parent.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

This didn't work for me. The `keys` list only contained the first key `settings` and hasn't got the other ones.

There is a `path` property which shows the path of the node you are in but it doesn't show the complete path of the JSON object.

[image]

How can I get the absolute path like in my example?

Comment: The absolute path to _what_? Where do you define you want the value of "type"? Anyway see https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsonpath

Comment: i don't want the value of "type". I want all the keys of my json object and then connect them to a path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your question you are asking how to get the path to "my JSON object", but your sample JSON actually contains *four* objects, nested.  (Each object begins with `{` and ends with `}` in the JSON.)  So the path will be different depending on which JSON object you are referring to.  It looks like you currently have a reference to the outermost object which you are querying to get the names of its properties.  But this won't give you the descendant properties, as you've seen.  What you need is to get the `Path` from the *innermost* property.

So I think we can boil your question down to this:

> *Given some JSON, how do I get the full path(s) to the deepest value(s) within the hierarchy (i.e. the leaf nodes)?*

You can do that with this [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) query:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);

var paths = obj.DescendantsAndSelf()
               .OfType<JProperty>()
               .Where(jp => jp.Value is JValue)
               .Select(jp => jp.Path)
               .ToList();
```

If you only want the first one, then replace `.ToList()` with `.FirstOrDefault()`.

Note that the path(s) will be returned with dots as delimiters.  If you would prefer slashes, then add `.Replace('.', '/')` to `jp.Path` within the `Select()` method call.

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lFXtEE

Answer (score 1):

Your parent object only has one key and that is "settings".  Its value is a json object.  That object has only one key and that is "general".  Its value is a json object.  That object has only one key and that is "database".  Its value is a json object.  You are using nested objects so you have to be specific about 'wanting all the keys' of which object.

Comment: I didn't notice this. To be exact i am trying to get every single key of the nested object. Like you said I want the key "settings" ob the parent object. It's value is a json object. That object has only one key and that is "general". I also want this. At the end i would have the keys in this order: settings, general, database, type

Answer (score 1):

The SO answer you referenced is not working because it is only giving you all the keys in your root object as a list of strings.

What you want is a recursive way to get all the "keys" (JProperty.Name).
If you have your `JProperty` with `Name = "type"`, let us call it `JProperty typeProp;`. Then `typeProp.Parent` will get you the `JContainer` containing `""type"" : ""PostgreSql""` and `typeProp.Parent.Parent` will get you a `JProperty` with `Name = "database"`.

So something like this might help (beware, untested):

```
JToken current = typeProp;
string path = "";

while (current != null)
{
    path = current.Name + "/" + path;
    if(current.Parent != null) current = current.Parent.Parent;
}
```

This will leave you with an extra slash on the end like this:

```
settings/general/database/type/
```

which you can remove with:

```
char[] charsToTrim = {'/'};
path.trimEnd(charsToTrim)
```