# Can't get the property of json object

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to get the property of this json:

```
{
  "dateFrom": "2021-01-01",
  "dateTo": "",
  "totalOrderCount": 2,
  "ordersPerPage": 1000,
  "pageNumber": 1,
  "error": null,
  "orders": {
    "50000": {"offerId": 595},
    "50001": {"offerId": 595}
  }
}
```

This is my code:

```
string content = "{... json ...}";
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(content);
dynamic GartnerOrders = data.orders;
```

With that I can acces the orderId like this:

```
foreach (var order in orders)
{
    string offerId= order.Last.offerId;
}
```

But how do I get the orderNo? Here 50000 and 50001

Comment: Deserialize it to POCO and be done with it. Orders will be a dictionary

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522358/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-keys-from-json-net

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yTQbb6

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052293/deserialize-json-to-c-sharp-classes

Comment: If you really wanted to do this the slowest most cumbersome way possible `var result = JObject.Parse(input)["orders"].Cast<JProperty>().Select(x => (x.Name, Value :x.Value["offerId"].ToObject<int>()))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var jsonDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json); 
jsonDeserialized.ordersList= jsonDeserialized.orders
Select(kvp => new Order { OrderNo=kvp.Key, offerId =kvp.Value.offerId}).ToList();

var order=jsonDeserialized.ordersList.Where(i=> i.OrderNo=="50001").FirstOrDefault() ;
```

output

```
{"OrderNo":"50001","offerId":595}
```

classes

```
public class Order

{
    public string OrderNo {get;set;}
    public int offerId { get; set; }
}


public class Root
{
    public string dateFrom { get; set; }
    public string dateTo { get; set; }
    public int totalOrderCount { get; set; }
    public int ordersPerPage { get; set; }
    public int pageNumber { get; set; }
    public object error { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Order> orders { get; set; }
    public List<Order> ordersList {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily as @TheGeneral mentioned - by deserializing it as a POCO.

See example using JsonSoft below:

Define the classes:

```
public class Data {
    public stirng dateFrom { get; set; }
    public stirng dateTo { get; set; }
    public int totalOrderCount { get; set; }
    public int ordersPerPage { get; set; }
    public int pageNumber { get; set; }
    public stirng error { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    
}

public class Orders {
    public int OfferId { get; set; }
}
```

Import NewtonSoft.Json

Now deserialize the json:

```
var data = Json.Deserialize<Data>(json);
```

Then you can do what you want:

```
var oders = data.Orders;

foreach (var order in orders)
{
    ...
}
```